# Do people who do math in universities draw asymptote $x=-1$ of non-linear asymptote $y=\frac{1}{x+1}$?

Tags: graphing-functions

For mathematics at GCE A-level, I was taught that the oblique asymptote $y=x+1$ (in graph of $y=f(x)$) becomes horizontal asymptote $y=0$ (in graph of $y=\frac{1}{f(x)}$).

However, I heard that people who do mathematics in universities learn that the oblique asymptote $y=x+1$ (in graph of $y=f(x)$) becomes non-linear asymptote $y=\frac{1}{x+1}$ (in graph of $y=\frac{1}{f(x)}$). If so, do these people draw asymptote $x=-1$ of the non-linear asymptote $y=\frac{1}{x+1}$ when asked to draw graph of $y=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ given $f(x)=x+1+\frac{1}{x}$?

I think it doesn't hurt to draw but it makes the whole graph slightly more messy.

I tried searching online for such graphs but could only find polynomial asymptotes at http://www.justinmath.com/graphing-rational-functions-with-slant-and-polynomial-asymptotes/.

Comment: I think for most people, if you asked them to draw the graph of $y = \frac1{f(x)}$, they wouldn't draw any asymptotes at all. Why would they? You didn't ask them to draw any asymptotes.

Comment: It depends on whether you want to restrict "asymptote" to polynomials or to something more general (e.g. rational functions). However, for graphing rational functions it makes little sense to use rational functions as asymptotes, since then the original rational function will always be an asymptote (which doesn't help in studying properties of the original function by using "simpler" functions). On the other hand, for non-rational functions approximations by rational functions can be useful (e.g. see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2930615/13130)).

Comment: To more directly address your question, this is an issue that varies with author, with teacher, with course level, etc. You're asking for a definitive meaning of something that has many different meanings, like asking whether people who teach computer programming in universities always tell their students to end each line of code with a semi-colon (what I was taught, this being [PL/I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I) back in 1977).

Comment: Thank you, @MishaLavrov!

Comment: Thank you, @DaveL.Renfro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether one asymptote "becomes" another asymptote is not a clearly defined question.

It is valid to state that if $y = f(x)$ has the asymptote $y = x+1$ (the two curves get arbitrarily close) as $x \to \infty$, then $y = \frac1{f(x)}$ has the asymptote $y = \frac1{x+1}$ as $x \to \infty$. This remains valid if we replace $x+1$ by any expression that goes to $\infty$ with $x$.

It is also valid to go further and say that since $y = \frac1{x+1}$ has the asymptote $y=0$ as $x \to \infty$, so does $y = \frac1{f(x)}$. If two things get arbitrarily close to the same thing, they get arbitrarily close to each other.

Both statements are true, though I think the second is more useful than the other, since $y=0$ is a simpler function than $y = \frac1{x+1}$. Some people might not be willing to consider the $y = \frac1{x+1}$ statement at all, if they are not interested in that kind of asymptote. They don't really lose anything by it - but that has no bearing on whether it's true or false.

But to answer your question, just because $y = \frac1{f(x)}$ has the asymptote $y = \frac1{x+1}$ as $x \to \infty$, and $y = \frac1{x+1}$ has the vertical asymptote $x=-1$ as $x \to -1$, it is not valid to conclude any relationship between $y = \frac1{f(x)}$ and $x=-1$. The limits $x \to \infty$ and $x \to -1$ are different, and asymptotes are all about behavior in a limit.